# Why do bookmarklets use iframes?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

After reverse engineering the bit.ly and delicious bookmarks I notice they both create iframes.

Is this so that the bookmarklet will have access to the user's information.  I don't see any other way that the bookmarklet would know who is creating the bookmarklet.

But there is a pattern in both.  The Bookmarklet is just a dumb place holder that calls the actual script.  This is so that the bookmarklet can be updated as the code dragged into the bookmark bar is somewhat permanent.

The code that is called then creates and iframe by specifying a url to either bitty or delicious which also contains GET parameters of the information to be saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mentioned bookmarklets might be using iframes, because then they could be styled specifically and include JavaScript which doesn't conflict with the JavaScript of the website.

The GET parameters are being used to transfer the required data from parent to child window without cross-frame scripting protection.

Comment: I agree with you, but what do you think about user identification.  The child window will now have the url and title of the parent, but how does it know which user on bitly wants to make the save?

Comment: The iframe loads a page which has some cookie with user session id (from the last login). By that, the server knows which user it is and saves the website link for him or her.

Comment: it could use `localStorage` as well I take it?

Comment: In general the content in the iframe could use localStorage, but for session authentication usually cookies are used, because they can be set from the server without JavaScript.